# TableViewCell 's textLabel and detailTextLabel is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The command cell.textLabel.text and cell.detailTextLabel.text is providing output in console but it does not give any value on the table view on simulator...

This is the code for generating the cell i have used..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"bookCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  // Book *bookDetail=[booksArrayDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    cell.textLabel.text= [self titleForRow:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"title for row= %@", cell.textLabel.text);

    cell.detailTextLabel.text= [self subtitleForRow:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"subtitle for row= %@",cell.detailTextLabel.text);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Test with [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self titleForRow:indexPath]] like that.

Comment: try applying some color and font to it...

Comment: Update your query with that methods  titleForRow and subtitleForRow.

Comment: Hey Ganapathy they are working properly..because the console showing that the  NSLog(@"title for row= %@", cell.textLabel.text);NSLog(@"subtitle for row= %@",cell.detailTextLabel.text); showing that the title and subtitle has been setted properly...but They are not seen on simulator...

Comment: check your delegate methods once. No. of rows and no. of selections whether its returning properly.

Comment: Yes they are working properly..

Comment: So empty cell only you are getting or app get crash?

Comment: So in console, you see some `title for row= abcd`, but not in the app? Do you see the table (separators)?

Answer (score 0):

go to your storyboard/xib and change the cell type from dynamic to subtitle.

whatever you have here, will not be executed:

```
if (cell == nil)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If your loading string value in cell use following statement:

```
cell.textLabel.text =[[YOURArray_Name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue]; (or)
cell.textLabel.text =[[YOURArray_Name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] description];
```

If your loading integer value in cell use following statement:

```
cell.textLabel.text =[[YOURArray_Name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];
```

If your loading Float value in cell use following statement:

```
cell.textLabel.text =[[YOURArray_Name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
```

Comment: Of course. You are assigning `int` and `float` to `NSString` property. That will not compile.